# The method setBitmapImage(Bitmap) is undefined for the type ImageView

Tags: android

I am trying to display an image downloaded from internet (my first try in android for an internet connection) but am getting an error which I cannot find anywhere on internet. The relevant code is:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
img.setBitmapImage(bitmap);
```

and the error is:The method setBitmapImage(Bitmap) is undefined for the type ImageView

The nearest I can find is that this method is undefined for type Bitmap and the people answering say to use a type of ImageView - which is exactly what (I think) I am doing!

Comment: Always check the doc first : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`setImageBitmap()` instead](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29).

Answer (score 0):

You know, you should press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>Space</kbd> to see whether the method exists or not.

The method name is `setImageBitmap(Bitmap bmp)` not `setBitmapImage`

Answer (score 0):

Because ImageView does not have this method. Use this one instead.

```
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```